# Why do computer programs (Wolfram Alpha, Symbolab) think $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n!)$ is divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

I've been recently looking at the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n!)=1+1+0+0+0+0+0+\cdots,$$

which should equal $2$. However, programs such as Wolfram Alpha, Symbolab, etc., tell me that this series is divergent. Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: The sum certainly equals $2$. I have no idea why Wolfram Alpha would think it is not convergent...

Comment: With Wolfram Alpha you get what you pay for.

Comment: The series becomes divergent if you work with $3.1415926535897932$ instead of $\pi$, for example

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown The same result happens on Wolfram Mathematica, where you pay quite a lot more...

Comment: Weird, Matlab doesn't evaluate it as well.

Comment: Maple computes it correctly if you use evalf...

Comment: If you just enter the series in Maple, you get the series back without an evaluation.  However, if you apply the command  evalf  , you get 2 as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, the software isn't clever enough to get the trick here.  I suspect that when Wolfram Alpha says the series is divergent, what it really means is that it is unable to determine that the series is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ge 2$ we have

$\frac{\pi}{2}n!= \pi k_n$ with $k_n \in \mathbb N$. Hence:

$\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}n!)=0$ for $n \ge 2$ and the series is convergent.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP knows that the sum is 2, and says so in the question.

Comment: Yes I know: downvoting makes a lot of fun .

Comment: @MartinArgerami Well, the OP only stated that it *should* converge and literally asked "Convergent or Divergent?"

Comment: @Martin Argerami That may be true, but it shows that the question is bad, not the answer: to assume that Wolfram Alpha or similar programs can walk on water is naive at best.